# Android - Show live video frames on ImageView object - Thread, AsyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, camera, android-asynctask, imageview

I am trying to display live video frames in a target ImageView object. The point is that I do not want to use the whole surface, because there are more controls in the layout (i.e. buttons,...).
I guess that a Thread or AsyncTask should be used, but I do not figure out how to do it.
Any tip is very welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your camerapreview surface any size you want, it's a UI element like any other.

Alternatively you can grab frames as a bytestream from the onPreview callback (as NV12), decode to jpeg using [YuvImage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html) and turn them into a bitmap using BitmapFactory, and then display the bitmap in your imageview.

I did something similar, but with two phones instead of one, [here](https://code.google.com/p/mover-bot/source/browse/trunk/Android-1.0/src/com/agentx3r/moverbot/RoverServerActivity.java#556) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/mover-bot/source/browse/trunk/Android-1.0/src/com/agentx3r/moverbot/RoverClientActivity.java#442).

Comment: You will definitely need threading, try using ByteInput/OutputStream.

Comment: Many thanks!
Your answer was really useful.
The combination of Thread and Handler did the job!